# How to compare an object's color property | Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I know how to set the value of an object's color property, but I'm failing in checking the same.
I need to compare the color of an object's mesh so that I can manipulate it if the condition is true.

Basic code:

```
object.traverse( function( child ) { 
    if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) { 
        child.castShadow = true;
        child.material.color.set(0x00ff00);
        if ( child.material.color == '0x00ff00' )   {  //this comparison check
            child.material.color.set(0x0000ff);
        }
    } 
} );
```

Is this comparison correct, or is there another way to check this property's value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare colors using a pattern like so:

```
var color = new THREE.Color( 0xff0000 ); // create once and reuse if needed

console.log( material.color.equals( color ); );
```

three.js .r85

Comment: I forgot the 'equals' method.
Thank You. That helped.